# How to access the super-class's private member in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, private, superclass, ecmascript-next

In a `class`, how do I access its base-class's private field, say `#property`?

```js
class Base {
  #property = '1.618'
  toString() {
    return Base.name
  }
}
class X extends Base {
  thisWorks() {
    return super.toString()
  }
  toString() {
    return super.#property // SyntaxError: Unexpected private field
  }
}
console.log(`${new X}`)
```

Comment: it is impossible I think. From object oriented perspective, it needs to be protected or public to be accessed.

Comment: just fyi, protected member access is doable, I actually did it once as an experiment, but it's very kludgy and performance suffers.  basically a wrapper for building a class which is fed functions and properties on a prototype object, which are then weakmapped and checked against function.caller in getters for each method name

however function.caller is now deprecated and doesn't look like there will be a replacement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [impossible](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/master/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md):

> It means that private fields are purely internal: no JS code outside of a class can detect or affect the existence, name, or value of any private field of instances of said class without directly inspecting the class's source, unless the class chooses to reveal them. (**This includes subclasses** and superclasses.)

`Base` would have to deliberately expose its `#property` in some other way, like through a method.

Comment: I see. Any why was it designed this way, specifically why exclude subclasses?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's for the sake of encapsulation, see [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/master/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md#why-does-this-proposal-allow-a-class-to-have-a-private-field-x-and-a-public-field-x) - every class can have its own private properties, even of the same name as private properties on the superclass, without collisions.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Indeed there is no collision, but logged to the console it looks somewhat odd: `{#property: 1, #property: 2}`. However I can see how this prevents discovering the names of a class's private properties via "brute-force"

Answer (score 3):

In OOP you can not access `private` method or property outside of the class even when you extend. But you can access `protected` method of parent class in child class.

Comment: Yes, however this question is about `#`-properties in JavaScript specifically, which has no `protected` and `#` is only casually called "private"

Comment: Well in my knowledge there is no way you can have protected method or property in JavaScript.  But you can simply '_' sign in front front of Identifiers to identify it as private but still it can be accessed outside the class.